# Undertow java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException when saving a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, undertow

I am new to using undertow and I have an issue when uploading files in  my spring boot application. This is happening in production only, it is working fine in my local system and staging environment (all Linux servers). This is the code:

```
public static String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, Long partnerId) throws Exception {
    if (multipartFile == null || multipartFile.isEmpty())
        return null;
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + UUID.randomUUID() + "."
        + FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
    multipartFile.transferTo(file);
    System.out.println("File Path "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    return uploadFile(file, partnerId);
}
```

The error is:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/undertow.3862881763240028662.4010/undertow3870310975240593973upload
at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.beginPart(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:261)
at io.undertow.util.MultipartParser$ParseState.headerName(MultipartParser.java:208)
at io.undertow.util.MultipartParser$ParseState.parse(MultipartParser.java:123)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:232)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:835)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:714)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/undertow.3862881763240028662.4010/undertow3870310975240593973upload
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:852)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.beginPart(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:254)
```

I can see the /tmp/undertow folders created in the staging environment:[image]

But the /tmp folder in production is empty after deployment. The file permissions etc for both servers are same. Any help here is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Look at the message. You are creating an additional directory which, by definition almost, does not exist.

Comment: @g00se any idea from where it is being created or how I can control the creation? For me it is created automatically when I start the application, but I don't know why it is not working in production.

Comment: `FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));` Debug the value of that separately and let us know. Also this debug: *System.out.println("File Path "+file.getAbsolutePath());* comes in the wrong place, as an attempt (failing) has already been made by then